# How to hide a description area and make it appear when you click on the photo?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So, I have two pictures on my site. Each picture has a description box beneath them. When you click on the desciption box, a description of that product appears. However, I want the description box to appear when you click on the picture itself, and not when you click on the description box. I have added an example of what I mean, but that site uses Shopify. I was wondering if something like that is possible on wordpress to and how?

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYg2w.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use script for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showImageDesc(obj) {
        var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
        if (inner.style.display == "none")
            inner.style.display = "";
        else
            inner.style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>

<div class="image-block">
    <img onclick="showImageDesc(this);" src="yourimage.jpg" />
    <div class="inner" style="display:none;">
        Here is your image description
    </div>
</div>
```